# Typesetting algorithms in LaTeX like Knuth

Tags: algorithms, typography

Is there any LaTeX package for typesetting algorithms in the style Donald Knuth uses in *The Art of Computer Programming*?

I know about the [`algorithm2e`](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.pdf) package, but I am looking for something that produces output like this:

**1.** [Check for lower bound.] If `X < lower_bound`, go to 3.

**2.** [Check for upper bound.] If `X > upper_bound`, go to 4.

...

I suppose I can use `\newcommand` and define my own macro, but I was hoping for something with more intelligence.

Comment: Just as a matter of personal opinion, Knuth’s style of typesetting algorithms is horrible. He intentionally shirks control structure and only uses jumps, which completely obscures the structure of the algorithm – this is the *last* thing you want for pseudocode. He also groups several operations in a single statement, thus obscuring the code further. Please don’t use this style.

Comment: @Konrad: I am actually just trying to describe a series of steps, not a computer algorithm. For that, I think Knuth's style is appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `listings` package, which has support for typesetting literate code. You need to set the replacement parameters first using `\lstset{literate=}`. This will replace for example `:=` with $\gets$ etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{literate={:=}{{$\gets$}}1 {<=}{{$\leq$}}1 {>=}{{$\geq$}}1 {<>}{{$\neq$}}1}
\begin{lstlisting}
var i:integer;
if (i<=0) i := 1;
if (i>=0) i := 0;
if (i<>0) i := 0;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The setting is a bit tedious and the details can be found on page 48 of the `listings` package (just `texdoc listings`) from a command prompt interface.

Answer (score 13):

Actually, Donald Knuth's macros for writing *The Art of Computer Programming* are available [online](http://ftp.cs.stanford.edu/tex/local/lib/taocpmac.tex)

These can be modified for LaTeX in a straightforward way, e.g.:

```
% These macros are borrowed from TAOCPMAC.tex
\newcommand{\slug}{\hbox{\kern1.5pt\vrule width2.5pt height6pt depth1.5pt\kern1.5pt}}
\def\xskip{\hskip 7pt plus 3pt minus 4pt}
\newdimen\algindent
\newif\ifitempar \itempartrue % normally true unless briefly set false
\def\algindentset#1{\setbox0\hbox{{\bf #1.\kern.25em}}\algindent=\wd0\relax}
\def\algbegin #1 #2{\algindentset{#21}\alg #1 #2} % when steps all have 1 digit
\def\aalgbegin #1 #2{\algindentset{#211}\alg #1 #2} % when 10 or more steps
\def\alg#1(#2). {\medbreak % Usage: \algbegin Algorithm A (algname). This...
  \noindent{\bf#1}({\it#2\/}).\xskip\ignorespaces}
\def\algstep#1.{\ifitempar\smallskip\noindent\else\itempartrue
  \hskip-\parindent\fi
  \hbox to\algindent{\bf\hfil #1.\kern.25em}%
  \hangindent=\algindent\hangafter=1\ignorespaces}
% end of borrowed macros

% For Example, with less than 10 steps:
% \algbegin X (Multiplication). blah blah blah blah...
% \algstep X1. [{\it Do stuff\/}] blah blah blah
% \algstep X2. Terminate the algorithm.\quad\slug
```