# Style used for Knuth's "The Art of Computer Programming"

Tags: memoir, typography, knuth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typesetting algorithms in LaTeX like Knuth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44019/typesetting-algorithms-in-latex-like-knuth)

Does anyone know if there is a style that mimics Knuth's *The Art of Computer Programming*? Baring that, would anyone know how to customize the memoir class to get an analogous result?

Comment: I took a look at that discussion but had problems understanding how to modify the TeX macros for use with LaTeX. I was hoping more for a LaTeX documentclass or something along those lines (or at least more help in making the translation).

Comment: If your question would be really different, please edit it to make clear what is desired. For example, your question doesn't state that *LaTeX* is desired to implement that TeX style (Do you mean algorithms? Page layout? ...). For now we close as a duplicate. It may be reopened if meaningful.

Comment: Regarding your comment question *how to modify the TeX macros* you could post a specific question.